# Oscillation frequency / criteria from Bode plot, negative feedback system

Tags: amplifier, oscillator, control-system, stability, bode-plot

Got a question, which is very integral to a project that I am writing a report for (which I am to hand in soon, so in a hurry).

Question:

1. What will my oscillation frequency be?
2. How will it be affected by reductions/increases to my gain (assuming phase unchanged)?

Edit: It is my understanding that the circuit will oscillate at the frequency where the gain reaches zero, assuming the phase margin is below 0. I am not certain this is correct.

Suppose I have a bode diagram as can be seen below. The gain is 0dB at 2.5MHz. The phase margin is -74 degrees.

The first image is the loop gain. The second is the phase in degrees. Note that it starts at -180 degrees.

[image: Bode plot around instability]

Context: The system is a self oscillating class D amplifier. The important takeaway here is that I want the amplifier to oscillate. The output will be a square wave, which is clipped by the supply rail voltage. Thus, the system will 'clip' when becoming unstable.

For those interested, the topology is:

[image]

And my linearised model:

[image]

Thanks!

Edit: Below is a zoomed out bode plot, just for context:

[image]

Comment: A good reason to use a simulator.

Comment: @Andyaka For sure, which I am of course also doing! But I need to back up my hypothesis based on analysis! And my current understanding is that if you increase the gain, the oscillation frequency will increase, as the point where the gain crosses 0dB will increase in frequency!

Comment: Just to be sure: The shown BODE diagram is the loop gain? Another queston: The shown active block (triangle symbol) - can we assume that it represents an ideal opamp?

Comment: I forgot to specify. The first image is the loop gain (zoomed), the second is the phase. The active block represents an opamp (or rather comparator), yes. Only thing is that the output voltage of the opamp matters to the loop gain. One should expect a square wave on the output of the opamp if the circuit is oscillating.

Comment: And your question is: Under which condition will the closed-loop oscillate? I am afraid, we cannot use an IDEAL opamp model (for MHz frequencies).

Comment: @LvW How so? I have verified that the circuit will oscillate in simulations. I can post some results. I see a significant discrepancy between simulation and calculations (500kHz vs. 2.5MHz). However, the opamp/comparator isn't linear as far as I understand - thus my linearisation may very well be wrong! As far as I know this is a whole topic in itself, and the gain of the comparator is dependent on the modulation index.

Comment: @LvW My reply was a bit quick. The frequency where the gain reaches 0dB according to my bode plot is 2.5MHz, which is what I think my oscillation frequency will be. What I observe is in the order of 500-800kHz depending on modulation index of the amplifier. The rise time of the comparator/opamp is to be assumed very fast.

Comment: As I understand, your circuit is highly non linear due to the saturation. Perhaps linearization won't provide correct results. Read upon "*describing functions*" to incorporate the effect (partially) of non linearity on the actual gain and phase cross over frequency.

Comment: Perhaps effective gain is much lower due to saturation effects.

Comment: @AJN It is highly non-linear, and I would not expect perfect results from linearisation. This is also why my question was framed as a general question to some extent. I will take a look.

Comment: Upon my request you have confirmed that the active device would be an opamp. Now you say it is "highly non-inear". In this case, what is the meaning of the shown transfer function (which is per definition linear)?

Comment: @LvW I am essentially trying to linearise a non-linear system - not such an outlandish thought, but not necessarily that useful either. In my case I need more of a ballpark figure. At the moment, after tweaking some values, my linear model predicts an oscillation of around 2MHz and I observe around 1MHz in simulation. It is my understanding that the system would be linear if the signal at the comparator was a triangle - like a PWM based class D amplifier. It is however a low pass filtered square wave, which will have an integrating effect that lowers phase and hence the oscillation frequency.

Comment: OK - fine. And what is your problem NOW?